# How to createText and append text to an existing element e.g. empty span?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes, textnode

Everywhere I've searched I've only found ways to append a textnode after creating a new element. For example, they'll create a new paragraph (`p`) element, and afterwards they append the textnode to that new paragraph. But I want to add a textnode to an **existing** element (in my case, an empty span).

Link to code for example and clarification
http://pastebin.com/K1EBMr4Z

```html
<span class="span"></span> <!-- append textnode here -->
```

```js
function newFunction(){
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("OK");

    // Append my `textnode` to the empty span here
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's easy, target that span and append -> `document.querySelector('.span').appendChild(new_element)`

Comment: Use jquery and after you now that span was created set his value ok by classs!

Comment: You should definitively use more jQuery, it does all things.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but its a javascript assignment for school:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can add the text node as a child of the span using the `appendChild()` method.

For text you can also just set the `innerHTML` property of the span.

Both examples in a bin:

```
function newFunction(){
  var span = document.getElementById('my-span');
  var otherSpan = document.getElementById('my-other-span');

  span.innerHTML = 'Yo this is text';

  var textNode = document.createTextNode("OK");
  otherSpan.appendChild(textNode);
};

newFunction();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9pmhan8L/1/

Comment: is it possible to do this selecting a class or by tagname instead of an ID?

Comment: Absolutely possible. Replace `document.getElementById('my-span');` with `document.querySelector('.span')` to get the first element with `class="span"` or with `document.querySelector('span')` to get the first `<span>` element.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Use appendChild method.

```
 function newFunction(){
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("OK");
    document.querySelector(".span").appendChild(textnode);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the span an id, you can get it using document.getElementById() and then change the html within that element.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203134/adding-data-to-span-tag-dynamically) a link to a SO that does this.  Also, here's some docs for [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and [getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the node you want to append the textNode to first. Then, append the textNode to that selected node (in your case, the `.span` element).

```html
<span class="span"></span>
```

```js
function newFunction(){
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");

  // Select your existing element
  var empty_span = document.querySelector('.span');

  // Append the element
  empty_span.appendChild(textnode);
}

newFunction();
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zyrdaqm/) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use jQuery:

```
$('span').text('text');
```

or

```
$('span').html('<p>text</p>');
```

If you do not use it, use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span').innerHTM = '<p>text</p>';
```

Comment: Because it's not tagged with jQuery, obviously, that's why!

Comment: Asker doesn't say they have jQuery loaded.